# Comparison test on $1/(e^x)$ vs $1/(e^x+1)$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Comparison test says that if bigger function is convergent then smaller one must be convergent.But here in this example it doesn't work and I want to know why?

$1/(e^x)$ is bigger or equal to $1/(e^x+1)$    ( between zero and infinite)
Improper integral   $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(e^x)} dx$ is convergent and it is $1$
however, improper integral $\int_0^\infty\frac{ 1}{ (e^x+1)}dx $ is divergent.

Comment: The second integral is not divergent. It is equal to $ln(2)$. Please check your computations.

Comment: thanks but :( i cant understand how , because there is inf-inf . lim(t->inf)[t-ln(1+e^t)+ln(2)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has
$$
0<\frac1{e^x+1}<\frac1{e^x},\qquad x\ge0,
$$ giving
$$
0<\int_0^\infty\frac1{e^x+1}\:dx<\int_0^\infty\frac1{e^x}\:dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\left[-e^{-x} \right]_0^M=\color{red}{-0}+1<\infty
$$ and one may observe that
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac1{e^x+1}\:dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\int_0^M\frac{e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\:dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}\left[-\ln(1+e^{-x}) \right]_0^M=\color{red}{-0}+\ln 2.
$$